# T0rlib4j - Make Java app access web via Tor

Tags: proxy, connection, java, torify

I went through all https://github.com/PanagiotisDrakatos/T0rlib4j/tree/master/src/main/java/net/sf/T0rlib4j/samples code, I read readme and searched internet for serveral hours but can't figure out how to make it work.

My goal is to make my app access web via Tor network. This looks like only usable Java library today. Have you any idea how to use it?

I've got Jsoup part to do the data mining, only thing left is how to make it go via Tor.

Answer (score 0):

Well, basically you don't need **any** custom libraries for Java or any other language **unless** you're about to use object-oriented bindings to Tor Control Protocol(you can use it as a plaintext telnet for a simple commands like `SIGNAL NWEWNYM` to change the circuits - it will be handy for a data gathering you've mentioned). All you really need to utilize Socks5**s** proxy protocol to make sure that DNS will be resolved through a proxy server(Tor's backend). But you can do it even more easier: use Tor's built-in HTTPS proxy to make a `CONNECT` call to the hostname you desire. That's it! No rocket science or custom libraries required!